# Finding value of closest set of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got multiple sets of radio buttons and am trying to use the `.find()` function to dynamically find the value of radio buttons in the same grouping.

However, it keeps returning undefined.

```
<fieldset>
  <div id="border1">
    <input id="radio1a" type="radio" id="set1" class="animals radio" value="Zebra">
    <input id="radio1b" type="radio" id="set1" class="animals radio" value="Lion">
  </div>
  <div id="border2">
    <input id="radio2a" type="radio" id="set2" class="fruit" value="Oranges">
    <input id="radio2b" type="radio" id="set2" class="fruit" value="Grapes">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div class="border1">
    <input id="radio3a" type="radio" id="set3" class="animals radio" value="Monkey">
    <input id="radio3b" type="radio" id="set3" class="animals radio" value="Parrot">
  </div>
  <div class="border2">
    <input id="radio4a" type="radio" id="set4" class="fruit radio" value="Bananas">
    <input id="radio4b" type="radio" id="set4" class="fruit radio" value="Cherries">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

(Sorry, didn't mean to put the same IDs. Was a copy/paste.)

I'm trying to use jquery to dynamically find the values:

```
$(".animals .radio").change(function()
{
  alert($(this).closest('fieldset').find('.fruit').val());
  etc.
}
```

But it keeps returning `undefined`

Also tried:

```
$(this).closest('fieldset').find('.fruit:checked').val()
```

Is there another way I should be approaching this?
I don't want to have to write code for every single set of radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It should `.animals.radio`, not `.animals .radio`.

1. `.animals.radio` means these two classes belongs to same element. (in your case this is right)
2. `.animals .radio` means `.animals` is ancestor of `.radio`.

   ```
    $(".animals.radio").change(function() {

      alert($(this).closest('fieldset').find('.fruit').val());

    });
   ```

AND ONE THINK, YOUR CODE HAVE ***DUPLICATE IDS***, AVOID IT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test it out.
(Didn't mean to put duplicate IDs. Was a quick copy/paste.)

Answer (score 2):

`$(".animals .radio")` is not the query you are looking for, it should be `$(".animals.radio")` (no white space between classes).

`$(".animals .radio")` looks for an element with class "radio" inside an element with class "animals".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test it out.
(Didn't mean to put duplicate IDs. Was a quick copy/paste.)

Answer (score 2):

How about not using `id=""` twice, and setting a `type="radio"` on those inputs for starters ?
You are also using the same ID for multiple elements, stop that ?

It should probably be :

```
<fieldset>


<div id="border1">
      <input type="radio" id="radio1a" name="set1" class="animals radio" value="Zebra" />
      <input type="radio" id="radio1b" name="set1" class="animals radio" value="Lion" />
  </div>
  <div id="border2">
      <input type="radio" id="radio1c" name="set2" class="fruit" value="Oranges" />
      <input type="radio" id="radio1d" name="set2" class="fruit" value="Grapes" />
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div class="border1">
      <input type="radio" id="radio2a" name="set3" class="animals radio" value="Monkey" />
      <input type="radio" id="radio2b" name="set3" class="animals radio" value="Parrot" />
  </div>
  <div class="border2">
      <input type="radio" id="radio2c" name="set4" class="fruit radio" value="Bananas" />
      <input type="radio" id="radio2d" name="set4" class="fruit radio" value="Cherries" />
  </div>
</fieldset>​​​​​​​​​​
```

To get both values :

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.fruit').each(function() {
         alert(this.value);
    });
}​);​
```

To get only the one that is checked :

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var elm = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.fruit').filter(':checked');
    alert(elm.value);
}​);​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test it out.
(Didn't mean to put duplicate IDs. Was a quick copy/paste.)

Answer (score 1):

`$(".animals .radio")` is getting you all the elements with class radio that have parents with class animals.

You want elements with both classes animals and radio, which is like `$(".animals.radio")`